# Notes view column with @DocChildren returns weird info when used in an Xpage

Tags: xpages

The following applies to Domino 8.5.3 FP3 UP1, design is done using Designer of the same version.

I'm having this Notes view with a column returning the number of DocChildren. The column formula is like this:

```
glViewTitle + " - " + @DocChildren("No comments"; "1 comment"; "% comments");
```

Using this view in the Notes client returns the expected result as in

[image: DocChildren view, Notes Client]

Showing the view using standard domino http it's working as well:

[image: DocChildren view, Domino http]

Using the view within an Xpage, however, displays the @DocChildren info in a very unexpected way:

[image: DocChildren view, Xpages]

I played around with that a little and found that if I use @DocDescendants in the column formula the Xpage code shows a "D" instead of the "C". The number behind the letter obviously refers to the number of arguments used with the @Function (0 .. 3).

Until today I believed that a NotesXspViewEntry would return everything as we see it in the correspponding Notes view, but this obviously is not the case.

Btw.: this behaviour not only applies to view panels or the like but also to values returned using the Xpages' flavour of @DbLookup etc..

some questions here:

- could this be some kind of bug? Or am I using that in the wrong way?
- What other options would I have apart from building a Notes view *without* DocChildren info and then using `NotesXspViewEntry.getChildCount()`?
- is there something else that can be used in a standard column formula but not in an Xpage context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other functions which are not working:

- @DocDescendants
- @DocLevel
- @DocNumber
- @DocParentNumber
- @IsCategory
- @IsExpandable

I think it is every @Formula affected which acts as a *"placeholder"* if the value is not known during computation of the column formula.

Comment: hmm - you're right (of course); I just saw that using a NotesViewEntry in LotusScript I get the same result. Kind of strange, still...